# Set current entity to an other

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.8

I work with symfony 2.8 and I have two entities : Cv and FormationCv , 
One Cv can have Many Formation Cv, so I try to do it with relation OneToMany and with collection Type

**CvType**

```
class CvForm extends AbstractType
{

   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $builder
             //..
            ->add('formations', CollectionType::class, array(

        'entry_type' => FormationCvForm::class,
        'allow_add'    => true,
        'by_reference' => false,

    ))             ;

}
```

**FormationCvType**

```
  class FormationCvForm extends AbstractType
{

   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
   {
    $builder->add('titre')
            ->add('etablissement')
            ->add('description')

            ->add('dateDebut', DateType::class, array(
                                              'widget' => 'choice', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle','data' => new \DateTime()))
            ->add('dateFin', DateType::class, array(
                                              'widget' => 'choice',
                                                    ))

            ;

}
```

**Controller**

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
  {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $cv = new Cv();

$form = $this->createForm('Front\FrontBundle\Form\CvForm', $cv);
$form->handleRequest($request);

 if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
       $user=$this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
        $cv->setEtudiant($user);
        $cv->setTelephone($user->getTel());
        $cv->setDateNaissance($user->getBirthday());
        $cv->setActif(false);




        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();



        $em->persist($cv);
        $em->flush();
        $formations=$cv->getFormations();
        $formation= array();
        foreach ($formation as $formations) {
            $formation->setCv($cv->getId());
            $em->persist($formation);
             $em->flush();

        }




        return $this->redirectToRoute('cv_show', array('id' => $cv->getId()));

    }

return $this->render("FrontBundle:CV:createCv.html.twig", array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),

    ));

 }
```

The problem that if I submit the form , in the table of FormationCv always get Null , 
Someone help me please ?

Comment: Did you take a look at your browsers POST request to see what was actually transferred?

Comment: Also: If your entity annotations are setup properly (eg. inversedBy and cascade) you can remove your last part (the whole foreach) in your controller since doctrine will handle that.

Comment: Plus: What is your foreach supposed to do? You initialize an empty array and try to loop over that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your foreach is not going to run a single iteration:

```
    $formations=$cv->getFormations();
    $formation= array();
    foreach ($formation as $formations) { // You're looping over $formation here, which is an empty array as per the line before this
        $formation->setCv($cv->getId());
        $em->persist($formation);
         $em->flush();

    }
```

Remove `$formation= array();` and switch your variables in the foreach condition: `foreach ($formations as $formation) {`.

Alternatively/Preferably: Get rid of the whole block and let doctrine do the work by setting up your entities to cascade persist operations and telling it about the inverse-side (mappedBy / inversedBy).